# How to translate JSP file into Servlet file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

**I tried to google a lot, but I couldn't find any page which can translate JSP file into Servlet.**

Comment: read about jsp and servlet. here's the link https://www.upgrad.com/blog/jsp-vs-servlet/#:~:text=Servlets%20are%20faster%20as%20compared,JSP%20are%20HTML%2Dbased%20codes.

Comment: If you are using tomcat, you can find servlets referring to your jsp files in a subdirectory of `/work/Catalina/localhost/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP files are transpiled to Servlets by Servlet Containers like those included in Tomcat and Jetty or application servers like WebSphere Application Server or Redhat's Enterprise Application Server or Wildfly.  The JSPs are deployed as part of a WAR and the container handles the rest as part of the deployment.

Comment: That is useful, but are there any online tools which we type JSP code into, then it converts that code into Servlet?

Comment: Not that I know of.  All of the JSP implementations that I'm aware of require classes that are not part of the standard and are provided by the container.  If you deploy your WAR to Tomcat or Wildfly, for example, you'll see the generated Servlet extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase and implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent,
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceImports.